# Scala foldLeft map and termCount of documents

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a list of documents and I want to find `(term -> termCount)` pairs over all the documents. Here is how I am doing it:

```
object termCount extends App {

  val docs = List(
    List("A", "B", "C", "C"),
    List("A", "D"),
    List("B", "B", "C"))

  val countsMap = docs.flatMap { ts =>
    val m = ts.map((_, 1)).groupBy(_._1)
    m.map { e => e._1 -> e._2.foldLeft(0)(_ + _._2) }
  }.groupBy(_._1)
    .map { e => e._1 -> e._2.foldLeft(0)(_ + _._2) }

  println(countsMap)

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Map(D -> 1, A -> 2, C -> 3, B -> 3)
```

To break it down into operations, what I am doing is:

- generating tuples of `(term, 1)`

  ```
  val m = ts.map((_, 1)).groupBy(_._1)
  ```
- calculating the document-local termCount `e => e._1 -> e._2.foldLeft(0)(_ + _._2)`
- generating a `Map` of document-local `(term -> termCount)` entries
- flattening this map back to tuples `(term, termCount)` across all documents
- also again doing a `foldLeft` to get global termcounts

My question is, how can I make this code more concise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty concise:

```
scala> docs.flatten.groupBy(identity).map { case (k,vs) => (k,vs.size)}
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(D -> 1, A -> 2, C -> 3, B -> 3)
```

One thing that would help out your original code is that you are performing the same foldLeft operation at two different levels: first on each sublist, then on the whole thing.  You could instead `flatten` the collection into one big list so you only have to do it once:

Btw: here's a foldLeft way:

```
docs.flatten.foldLeft(Map.empty[String,Int]){ case (z,x) => z.updated(x, z.getOrElse(x,0) + 1) }
```